# Tensorflow with bazel: avx ignored?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, compilation, bazel

I'm trying to compile tensorflow by hand to take Advantage of avx.
Unfortunately I it seems to be ignoring specifically these instructions.
I might add that I'm working on a Windows 10.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I used the following command for bazel:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

[image: Compile with bazel]

Comment: Those flags are for GCC (or Clang?), not for MSVC. Did you add them yourself or were they enabled by some build configuration parameter?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-mavx` and so on are for GCC and Clang compilers only. Since you are using MSVC, you should use `--copt=/arch:AVX --copt=/arch:AVX2` and so on instead.

Comment: how can I set msvc to optimize for the native machine? an equivalent to -march=native?

Comment: There is no "-march=native" equivalent for MSVC compiler, you will have to figure the chop architecture of your computer yourself, and use the correct `/arch:` compiler flag